# highslide.js don't show pop up images

Tags: javascript, highslide

i tried to make pop up images in my responsive gallery, but it seems to me that highslide.js doesn't see the pop up images. Script source http://highslide.com/#installation  I use bootstrap and Word Press. I see that images loading but can't appear. I spend much time but don't understand what I've done wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

My site http://b.pusku.com/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12 thumbs_color">
            <ul id="thumbs">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://b.pusku.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/7.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
                        <img src="http://b.pusku.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/test_carusel1.jpg" alt="test_carusel" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">
                        <img src="http://b.pusku.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/test_carusel1.jpg" alt="test_carusel" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/highslide/highslide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // override Highslide settings here
    // instead of editing the highslide.js file
    hs.graphicsDir = '/highslide/graphics/';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the hs.graphicsDir setting is wrong. Judging from the way you are inserting the template url in the path for the highslide.js file, my guess is that it should look like this:

```
hs.graphicsDir = '<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/highslide/graphics/';
```

If that doesn't work, there's a [FAQ item](http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=606) for it on the Highslide website.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't do it, but i have read that i need to do a few extra steps to make script working in Word Press. I will try again.